# NetworkManager and Qt Problem

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, dbus

I am still new to using Qt4/Dbus, and i am trying to get a list of acccess points with Qt API to send/receive Dbus messeges.
I got the following error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod
Method "GetAccessPoint" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless" doesn't exist
```

The code is:

```
QStringList *netList = new QStringList();
    QDBusConnection sysbus = QDBusConnection::systemBus();
    QDBusInterface callNM("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager","/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager","org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless",sysbus);
    if(callNM.isValid())
    {
        QDBusMessage query= callNM.call("GetAccessPoints");
        if(query.type() == QDBusMessage::ReplyMessage)
        {

            QDBusArgument arg = query.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
            arg.beginArray();
            while(!arg.atEnd())
            {                
                QString element = qdbus_cast<QString>(arg);
                netList->append(element);
            }
            arg.endArray();
        }else{
            std::cout<< query.errorName().toStdString() << std::endl;
            std::cout<< query.errorMessage().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
        int x= netList->size();
        for(int y=0; y< x ;y++)
        {
            widget.avail_nets->addItem(netList->at(y)); // just print it to my gui from the stringlist array
        }

    }else{
            std::cout<<"fail" << std::endl;
    }
```

Whats wrong?My naming was correct and I am following the exact specs from [here](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/spec-08.html#org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless)

Comment: Use a tool like d-feet to check the dbus interface of the running instance of NetworkManager.

Answer (score 1):

The method name is **GetAccessPoints**.

While your error is:

> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod
>   Method "GetAccessPoint" with signature
>   "" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless"
>   doesn't exist

Highlight on **"GetAccessPoint"**. Thus you might have misspelled the method name in the code, although the code you pasted here uses the correct method name, maybe you fixed it and forgot to rebuild or clean the project?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but then I noticed that it only happened when I called the `GetAccessPoints` method on a *wired* device. Make sure the device is a *wireless* device (i.e. `DeviceType` equals `NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI`), and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

i modify this and works for me

```
QDBusInterface callNM("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager","/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0","org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless",sysbus);
```

and the result is

```
"/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/2"
"/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/1"
```

i think `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager`  is not correct path for specific device (wireless devices).

Answer (score -1):

```
QDBusInterface dbus_iface("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager", "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0", "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless", bus);

QDBusMessage query = dbus_iface.call("GetAccessPoints");

if(query.type() == QDBusMessage::ReplyMessage) {

    QDBusArgument arg = query.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
    arg.beginArray();
    while(!arg.atEnd()) {
        QString element = qdbus_cast<QString>(arg);
        netList->append(element);
        showAccessPointProperties(element);
    }
    arg.endArray();
} else {
    qDebug() << "got dbus error: " << query.errorName();
    qDebug() << "check the parameters like service, path, interface and method name !!!";
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: From my git more proj. https://github.com/stoic1979/QtDbusNetworkManager